# videojs safari crash when fast-forwarding

Tags: javascript, video.js, video-embedding

videoJS sounds like a cute solution and we almost adopted it but there's two glitches in my attempts:

- the first is that on Safari 5.1.7 on MacOSX 10.6.8 (all latest in this row), a click to fast forward (i.e. right of the cursor) freezes Safari: the wait-wheel in rainbow colours keep spinning
- the second is that the same embedding simply displays nothing on MacOSX 10.7.5 with Safari 6.0.2

None of this happens in Chrome or Firefox.
And this does not happen on videojs.com.

However the code is pretty similar, the video files are copied (I hope this is ok): it can be played here: http://direct.hoplahup.net/tmp/videoJSattempt/video-iframe-attempt.html and the source is:

```
<html><head><title>videoJS attempt</title>

    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
</head><body>
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
       preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="/tmp/videoJSattempt/oceans-clip.jpg"
       data-setup="{}">
    <source src="/tmp/videoJSattempt/video/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="/tmp/videoJSattempt/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>

</body></html>
```

What are my options to debug this?
Or... is there something I did wrong?

thanks in advance

Paul